# Netoffice progid not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, netoffice

I've done find and replace solution in `Micorsoft.Office.Interop.Word` in asp.net I would like to move this solution on `NetOffice` in my asp.net server where there is no Microsoft Word. I got error

> progid not found

. What I do wrong because on my computer where I have Microsoft Word this code work fine in NetOffice?

`Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();` <-- here is this error

Comment: In NetOffice you may don't have Microsoft Word.

Comment: You said your asp.net server where there is no Microsoft Word. that's the key that you must install software Microsoft Office family. then your code will run well.

Comment: NetOffice is a wrapper to the office applications not a replacement, Word must be installed on the server.  Automating office from ASP.Net is not recommended anyway.

Comment: Is there any solution that my code will be work without install word on server or is there any package with code similar to Micorsoft.Office.Interop.Word where should work without install word ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NetOffice](https://github.com/NetOffice/NetOffice) is just a COM Wrapper to the office applications, therefore it requires that you have the office app installed on the machine where your application is running.

i.e. You need to have Microsoft Word installed on any machine that you intend to run an app that uses NetOffice.Word.

If this was a desktop app, all you would have to do, would be to install Word on the machine, but given [you want to use office automation from a server, and Microsoft does **not** recommend it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757), you should look into other options of interfacing with Word documents directly via OpenXML without having to install Word on the machine.

I'd recommend taking a look at the [DocX](https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX) library:
https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX

As well as the articles below:

- [How to: Create a word processing document by providing a file name (Open XML SDK)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478190.aspx)
- [Edit Word Documents using OpenXML and C# Without Automation/Interop](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/994905/Edit-Word-Documents-using-OpenXML-and-Csharp-Witho)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work with NetOffice, but you need to add a using statement:

```
using Word = NetOffice.WordApi;
```

You also need to disable the setting Embed Interop types for all NetOffice DLL's.